# why would you tar a zip file

Tags: tar, zip

I see [here](http://www.bitzipper.com/tar-file.html) that a **tar** is used to merge several files into one. So why do I see so often one **zip** file in a **tar**?

example : archive.zip.tar

Comment: That's not common at all in my experience, where did you see that? (`.tar.gz` and variations on the other hand _is_ extremely common.)

Comment: because people do all sorts of strange things.  and it's not illegal (or even immoral) to put a .zip inside a tar file.

Comment: Maybe someone put a zip in a tar file to avoid a naive email attachment filter.

Comment: why do *you* tar zip file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tar doesn't compress* - it's 'tape archive' and exists purely to serialise data - traditionally to a tape device.

It serialises a directory structure, including permissions and file contents.

`gzip` *doesn't* preserve structure, and just compresses on a 'file' bases - hence why you tend to get `.tar.gz` - it's a serialised structure that has then been compressed.

I don't know why you'd get `.zip.tar` though, given that `zip` *does* support directory structures, permissions and compression. It seems largely nonsensical to do so.

* newer versions of `tar` include the `z` flag to compress - this wasn't part of the original spec. So you'd `tar cvf - ./path_to_tar | gzip -c > file.tar.gz`

Comment: Doesn't it matter for the inode count? 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/436679/what-is-the-difference-between-different-compression-systems

Comment: You save the same number of inodes through tar and through zip; you save nothing if you use both at once.

Comment: Actually, just `tar cv ./path_to_tar | gzip ..`, `f -` is unnecessary.